# gta 5 - How to fix replay mission Big Score (obvious approach) freeze at door bug

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When I replay Big Score mission and choose obvious approach, then the game freeze at the cutscene where a player is opening a door: like this video:

It's annoying that I can't see the answer to this question when I search articles on the internet:

for example - R* support: [Freezing When Attempting to Replay "The Big Score" in GTAV](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/208355757-Freezing-When-Attempting-to-Replay-The-Big-Score-in-GTAV)

Comment: I post this question for future references purpose, I actually know how to fix this bug in the past, but after a long time, I forgot exactly how to fix it, but I vaguely remember it's because of the character when we replay the mission, then I go on the internet to search for which character cause the issue, but it took me sometime and can't find the answer. So I make this question to solve this issue one and for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this bug is: **start mission as Trevor**.

Step 1: Switch to **Trevor** if you are playing as Michael/Franklin.

Step 2: Start replay mission - Done! no more freezing.